# Streamtokenizer, whitespaces

Tags: java, whitespace, tokenize, java-io, removing-whitespace

I would like to use StreamTokenizer to extract a name from a java file. I have set the whitespaces as commas

```
        inputTokenizer.whitespaceChars(',', ',');
```

However when I parse the inputfile for a name( firstname lastname with a space in between) the tokenizer treats firstname as one token and lastname as another token. I would like both of them to be treated as the same token, how can I do this?

For Example "Billy Jean" is treated as two separate tokens(Billy - token1 Jean - token2) and I want it to be treated as one.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `split`? `inputLine.split(",")`

Comment: So what you're saying is: Use a scanner to read the whole line. Then split the line, then parse the line to extract whatever number/strings I need? Instead of using the streamtokenizer. How can I parse the line to make sure that the input is a word? Is there a String.parseWord sort of method?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, but what do you mean by a word? If you want to separate the string into an array of tokens, the `String.split(delimiter)` method does that.

Comment: The streamtokenizer can somehow determine if a token is word, I don't know how it does this. I'm wondering if the scanner has a similar functionality.

Comment: [Not seeing anything to do with words in the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html), could you please explain the behavior you are describing?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#TT_WORD for example

Comment: I don't think there's an automatic way to detect a word, but you can see if a token is a word by taking the return value of `inputLine.replaceAll("\\w","")` (this will not modify the original string) and seeing if the length of the method's return value is 0. What this does is removes all "word characters" (essentially letters and numbers) from the string and see if there are any characters left. If there are characters left, the token was not a single word.

Comment: Also, why do you need to detect words in your code?

Comment: I am reading from a file that should be formatted as follows:name, num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7, I need to make sure that each line starts with a name(word) and is then followed by 7 numbers

Comment: First, `split` the input line on `","`. Then, take the first element of the resulting array and call `array[0].replaceAll("\\w+\\s+\\w+","")`, then make sure that method's return value has a length of 0. If so, parse the rest of the line. You could also `split` the output of the first `split`, using space this time, and do `replaceAll("\\w+","")` on each element of the array, making sure that the result for each is equal to 0.

Comment: @Math, I used the following code:`private static Boolean testForWord(String[] a) throws formatError{
  String firstInput;
  Boolean proceed;
  firstInput = a[0].replaceAll("\\w+\\s+\\w+","");
  if(firstInput.isEmpty()){
   proceed = true;
  }//if the 1st token is a word
  else{
   proceed = false;
   System.out.println("Your file must start with a full name(first last) seperated by a comma");//why does this only work is there is a last name and not fr a first?
   throw new formatError();
  }//else if the 1st token isn't a word
  return proceed;
 }//test fr word`  this doesn't catch numbers

Comment: Am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that (evidently) spaces are regarded as delimiters by default (hardly surprising); you have set commas as whitespace characters, and so both commas and spaces are regarded as whitespace characters.  The following program does what I think you want; note the line that sets spaces to be "wordChars".

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.StringReader;


public class TokenTeaser
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      String testString = "one two, three, four five";
      StringReader sr = new StringReader(testString);
      StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(sr);
      st.whitespaceChars(',', ',');
      st.wordChars(' ', ' ');
      int currentToken = st.nextToken();
      while (currentToken != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF)
      {
        System.out.println(st.sval);
        currentToken = st.nextToken();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: While I tried to give a solution in the comments, +1 for integrating your solution with the OP's original approach and keeping it simple.

Comment: @arcy is there a way to tell the tokenizer to regard "sam" as a token in any given stream??

Comment: I don't know of one, and it doesn't seem reasonable to me that it should. This is a class meant to turn a stream of characters as a token based on individual characters as delimiters; certainly any token you want can be treated any way you want, but *this* class doesn't seem to deal with strings of characters as delimiters, only characters as delimiters.